# Jquery Cross Domain AJAX Communication with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I'm trying to create a simple login system that will have the  forms and everything on one domain (Let's call it Domain A) and the PHP files on another domain (Domain B). Why? Simply because Domain A is more reliable but doesn't support PHP. I'm quite new to all this AJAX stuff, so I'm currently using the resources I've found online.

The Jquery and Forms part of it on **Domain A** are as below:

```
<form id="submit" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter Information</legend>  

<label for="fname">Name:</label>  
<input class="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="20" type="text" />  

<label for="lname">Email:</label>  
<input class="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="20" type="text" />  

<button class="button positive"> Submit </button>  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {  
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below  
    var fname     = $('#fname').attr('value');  
    var lname     = $('#lname').attr('value');  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "http://domainB.com/somefolder/ajax.php",  
            data: "fname="+ fname +"& lname="+ lname,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});  

            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Please note that the 'lname' and 'fname' are going to represent Name and Email instead of Firstname and Lastname respectively.

The PHP code on **Domain B** :

```
<?php  

    // CLIENT INFORMATION  
    $uname        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));  
    $umail        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));  
  $uip = 12345;
  $usecret = "secret";
//Mysql
$con = mysql_connect("mysql.domainB.com","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
//Connect
mysql_select_db("login_db", $con);
//Insert user details irrespective of whether the user is a member or not to make a log kind of thing
mysql_query("INSERT INTO log_data (Name, Email, IP_ADDRESS, Secret)
VALUES ('$uname', '$umail', '$uip', '$usecret')");

//Now check if the user is a subscriber or not


//   mysql_query("SELECT Email, Secret FROM login_data WHERE Email='$umail' AND Secret="secret"");
//I don't know the code to check if the user has logged in correctly
//This is where I need you to help me
//I need to check if the user has logged in correctly, if yes, then return a message saying //success which should be caught by Jquery and displayed as an Alert, or something
//If the user login failed, this php code should return a failure message which again should be caught by Jquery on Domain A and displayed as an alert in the least.


mysql_close($con);
//end Mysql

?>
```

Things to note here - There are two tables inside the **login_db** database - **log_data** which stores the log information and the **login_data** which stores usernames and passwords. The variable $secret stores the user's password.

The log_data insertion works like a charm, but its the login_data that is bugging me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Imag

Comment: @imaginonic , is your php working idependent of jquery ajax , do one thing just execute php and see everything is working fine

Comment: @gov - Thank you gov, for the reply, the first query (insertion) works really fine, I just need to get the select query (second query) to work. Thanks

Comment: @imaginonic , if your insert is working , then its not a cross domain issue right, where is your select queryu???

Comment: @can you directly run the select query on database and see if it is working?? just trying to debug...don't mind

Comment: You're right, the insertion is working fine, the second query is commented: mysql_query("SELECT Email, Secret FROM login_data WHERE Email='$umail' AND Secret="secret"");

Comment: @imaginonic do one thing, print the above sql statement and see what it is and then take that sql statement and execute in database, i think there are no result sfor your select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a trying the below code...it should take care of cross domain issue also

```
var dataString = "fName=" + $('#fname').attr('value') + "&lname=" + $('#lname').attr('value');
                var url = "http://demo/exampe.php?" + dataString;


              $.getJSON(url + "&jsoncallback=?", function(data){

                alert("success");
```

jsonp object construction should be as below..

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}



                });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gov, I need to modify my PHP too, right? Because in my PHP I haven't used JSON encode anywhere. Thanks a million. Imag

Comment: @imagionoic , i don't know much about php but you need to form a string and conver to jsonp notation and send to the UI , you need to use that {} and [] braces to contruct the jsop object...

Comment: @imagionoic , see this example , he showed how to send a manually constructed string back to jquery , sorry as i am a .net person , couldn't help you much http://lnx.shortcutto701.com/2010/12/05/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery-jsonp-aspnet/

Comment: This helped me a lot Gov, thanks a ton. I'm really grateful to you for your time and effort. Do stay in touch. Have a great day!  Imag

Comment: Yes, using the first part of your code with some slight modifications as mentioned in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313813/using-jquery-ajax-to-load-info-from-database

Answer (score 0):

You can't do cross-domain ajax due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can do [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) cross domain. Her's how with JQuery: [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Ok, can't I even return an error message to my Jquery page? Somthing like if (function login fails) return error; ?? (Don't mind the syntax please)

Comment: @imaginonic , firebug tells you some extentn , but if you want to see you have to write your own exception and send the status to the UI as apart of your return string or jsonp object...

Comment: @larry , he is able to execute the insert statement, then it shouldn't be a cross domain issue right , the values are going fine in the insert statement..

Comment: Wow, thanks Gov, I'm really grateful to you for taking the time to help me here, but I really don't know to handle stuff with JSONp. If you can help me make modifications to the code above to handle JSON objects, that would be fine. Basically, I just need the user to enter his credentials on Domain A, check them using PHP on domain B and then return an error or success depending on the situation, which should be caught by Jquery. Thanks a lot

Comment: @imaginonic , are you sure that your problem is cross domain issue , then we can do a jsop example its not a big issue//

Comment: No, I think I misrepresented my situation here - The cross domain issue was only with the ordinary JQUERY code above (without using JSON).I think using JSON should work fine. I would be really grateful if you could help me out with an example using JSON (for my situation above). Thanks.

Comment: this link has some example , read this meanwhile i will try to find someother good one..http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks Gov, really, Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @imaginonic , i posted some example , please give a try//

Answer (score 0):

you should use datatype jsonp

```
$.ajax({
            url: url, 
            async: true, 
            type: "GET", 
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            success: function(json){
                // handle success response here
            },
            error: function(){ alert("x.err"); }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you AnD, I'll be even more grateful if you could show me how do I implement in my code above. I mean, I don't know how I could parse the usernames and passwords as JSON and retrieve a response from the PHP server from the same using your code. Thanks

Comment: first you have to make the response header from your php: Content-Type application/json, echo the response (json format) like usual, and then you can access your json data using jquery with .(dot) notation eg. var id = menu.id