# onclick on DIV, load content from database on other div

Tags: php, ajax, html

My concept is to load contents of a div on other div in html. In short I want to learn how the  new Facebook inbox works, when we click on a message on the right, the contents and fetched from the database and loaded in the center column. I know its done by some AJAX may be but unable to figure out how it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313813/using-jquery-ajax-to-load-info-from-database

Comment: I want a detail explaination...I'm a newbie to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jquery you can use onclick event on a div.

This is the HTML/JS this work like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document Title</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.clickable').on('click', function(){
                var data_id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id: data_id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#more-info').html(data.html);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        $('#more-info').html('');
                        alert('Error Loading');
                    }
                });
            });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="item-one" class="clickable" data-id="123">Click me</div>
        <div id="item-two" class="clickable" data-id="456">Click me</div>
        <div id="more-info"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and let say we have a PHP file named **ajax.php** will return a json like we especified before in the ajax function **dataType: 'json'** and we are sending an **ID** through POST so here are a example you have to work it on it.

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id = {$id} LIMIT 1"; //expecting one row
$result = mysql_query( $query );
$message = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); //expecting just on row

$json = array();
$json['html'] = '<p>' . $message . '</p>';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $json );
?>
```

Comment: the div id varies each time. Can that be same because i'm loading all the messages on the right panel using a while loop.

Comment: more-info represent the right panel, and `$message` in this case is one message, if you want you can use a while loop to load thoses messages into an array. and inside the `more-info` element `append` instead of use `$(element).html(val)` use `$(element).append(val)` and use a list instead of simple `<p></p>`

Comment: I want to know that once i click on a message, where will the content be loaded?

Comment: `success: function(data){
                        $('#more-info').html(data.html);
                    },` this will make it load inside the element with id `more-info`

Comment: Have i got is right: When i click on "Click Me" whose data-id is 123, the id is sent to the ajax.php file, which does a database search and sends a json back to the html page and the particular message is loaded into the mail-info div.