# How to generate asp.net control using markup in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

How do I generate the controls in a div based on the markup defined in a SQL Server database? Is it possible? If yes, then how? Can anyone give me resources?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Mode="Transform"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection _newConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand storedProcedure = new SqlCommand("sp_getMarkup", _newConnection);
            storedProcedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(storedProcedure);

            _newConnection.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            _newConnection.Close();

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table"];
            string s = (from str in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       where str.Field<int>("Id").Equals(1)
                       select str.Field<string>("elemMarkup")).SingleOrDefault().ToString();

            this.lit.Text = s;
        }
    }
}
```

In the database I have stored string as

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Now the problem is the control is rendered on page but is not visible. I can see it in view source.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Pretty much everything is possible, if you try.  Have you tried?  If so, show us the code.  See: **[FAQ: On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Comment: @MichaelBray I not sure how should I proceed. If you can point me to a direction, it will be helpful for me. Thanks for encouragement though,

Comment: Will this markup contain ASP.NET controls, or only HTML?

Comment: ASP.NET controls... why? does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes.  HTML can be thrown right on the page, where as ASP.NET controls need to be programmatically added to the control tree.

Comment: @MichaelBray I have added code as you had suggested, now can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx) which accepts a string and create controls on the fly.

The drawback is if server code is in the string, it will not be executed. In addition, you need to attach event manually such as button click events.

For example,

```
<script runat="server">
    // This server code will not be executed 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another SO question [using jquery ajax to load info from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313813/using-jquery-ajax-to-load-info-from-database)

I would recommend having some type of `sanitizing` intermediary; otherwise you are opening yourself up to cross-site scripting (XSS) issues.

Comment: I am not looking for using Jquery. I want to generate asp.net controls like label or checkbox whose markup is defined in database.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a placeholder on a page like so:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And in your code behind, you could have several checks (all of which contain SQL statements querying the data in the database). The database could contain a field containing component names such as checkbox, button (various other controls). This saves you storing markup in the database fields..

Very rough representation of how the code would look like..

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // SQL Code here

    // Datatable code here 
    // End of DataTable code

    // Beginning of IF blocks   
        If (DataTable.Rows.Count > 0) {
        If (your check != "checkbox") {
        this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Button(){
            Text = "Added"}
            }
          }
     // More if statements here
       );

    }
}
```

Alternatively if you insist on storing asp markup in the database, then you could just feed the asp markup into the placeholder using a loop (if there are more than one rows in your database)